# A question about Baby Rudin theorem 4.30, why is it possible to associate a different $r(x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, continuity, proof-explanation

I am currently reading Baby Rudin and I have some trouble understanding the proof

> **4.30 Theorem** Let $f$ be monotonic on $(a, b)$. Then the set of points of $(a, b)$ at
> which $f$ is discontinuous is at most countable.

> Proof Suppose, for the sake of definiteness, that $f$ is increasing, and
> let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous.
> With every point $x$ of $E$ we associate a rational number $r(x)$ such
> that
> $f(x-) < r(x) <f(x+)$.
> Since $x_1 < x_2$ implies $f(x_1 +) \leq f(x_2 - )$, we see that $r(x_1) \ne r(x_2 )$ if
> $x_1\ne x_2$ We have thus established a 1-1 correspondence between the set $E$ and
> a subset of the set of rational numbers. The latter, as we know, is countable.

I don't understand why it is possible to associate a different $r(x)$ for all $x$ , I think the reason why a monotone function can have at most countable discontinuities is that for any uncountable set of positive real numbers $S \ \ \ \sum\limits_{s\in S}s$ diverge to infinity and since $\sum\limits_ {x \in E}f(x+) - f(x-) <f(b-)- f(a+)$ so it is not uncountable (this is my understanding of this theorem maybe it is wrong) and since this was not been in the proof means Rudin didn't use it so lets for a minute imagine that there is uncountable set of positive real numbers $S \ \ \ \sum\limits_{s\in S}s$ converge then we can make a monotone function  with uncountably infinite discontinuities  then it would be impossible to associate a different $r(x)$ for all $x$

My example about uncountable infinite discontinuities is not a proof but a part of the question, since Rudin didn’t address the fact that any sum of elements of uncountable infinite set of positive reals diverges means He didn’t use it in his proof and that means the proof works without it (which I don't think is right if it can make a monotone function with uncountable infinite discontinuities  ). And here I am confused, since he didn’t address that and without mentioning this fact the proof is incomplete, except if the proof somehow implies that any uncountable infinite set of positive reals diverges.

Comment: Let $S$ be the discontinuity set and suppose it's uncountable. Put $S_{1/n} = \{x:f(x_+)-f(x_-)>1/n\}$. Then at least one $S_{1/n}$ is countable, and the thesis follows.

Comment: As for rudin's proof, let $x<y$ both be discontinuities. Then $(f(x-),f(x+))\cap (f(y-),f(y+)) = \varnothing$. Indeed, if not, then $f(y-) < f(x_+)$, contradicting the monotonicity of $f$.

Comment: However, do note that to prove it using the $S_{1/n}$ method, you do need to first overcome the difficulty that this is not immediately applicable as the domain of $f$ is open. Indeed, one actually needs $\sum_S f(x_+)-f(x_-)<\infty$, but it's possible $f(b-)$ or $f(a+)$ are infinite. If $f$ is defined at $a,b$, then all is well. I leave it to you to fix this technical difficulty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that if $f(x_+)>f(x_-)$ and $f$ is monotonic increasing, then there is no other point $x'$ such that $\big(f(x_-),f(x_+)\big)\cap \big( f(x'_-),f(x'_+) \big)\neq \emptyset$. Namely, any discontinuity has a corresponding nontrivial interval, corresponding to the jump in values, disjoint from the interval corresponding to any other discontinuity. If $r(x)$ would not be injective, then those intervals would have to intersect.

I think your alternative proof also works, but one must still argue why an uncountable sum of positive number must diverge.

Comment: "If $r(x)$ would not be injective, then those intervals would have to intersect." this is the part I don't understand why is true.

Comment: My example about uncountable infinite discontinuities is not a proof but a part of the question, since Rudin didn’t address the fact that any uncountable infinite set of positive reals diverges. He didn’t use it in his proof and that means the proof works without it. And here I am confused, since he didn’t address that and without mentioning this fact the proof is incomplete, except if the proof somehow implies that any uncountable infinite set of positive reals diverges.

Comment: @pie $r(x)$ is chosen from $\big(f(x_-),f(x_+)\big)$. So if $x<y$ are points of discontinuities of $f$ and $r(x)=r(y)$, you would get that $r(x)\in \big(f(x_-),f(x_+)\big)$ and also $r(x)=r(y)\in \big(f(y_-),f(y_+)\big)$.

Comment: @pie As for the alternative proof, I think Andrew clarified the other necessary steps. Indeed any uncountable sum of strictly positive numbers must diverge, by Andrew's first comment.